Looking for 80s film - kids, hacking, Big Trak, magnetic card
I'm looking for a film I saw in a computer camp 30 years ago. All I remeber is a group of kids who try to break into or out of a facility by using smart hacks. They used a magnetic tape on a plastic card to enter a door, reprogrammed a Big Trak-like robot (see picture) and so on. I would guess the film is from late 1979 to 1985.
It's not War Games nor Tron nor The Goonies, but a similar kind and era.

Big Trak programmable Toy Robot/Tank from 1979 

Could it possibly be The Manhattan Project (1986) ?

The Manhattan Project tells of how 17 year-old Paul Stephens
  (Christopher Collet) and his girlfriend Jenny Anderman (Cynthia Nixon)
  an aspiring journalist, wants to alert their community a secret
  nuclear facility in their hometown of Ithaca, NY. While Dr John
  Mathewson (John Lithgow), supposedly a doctor in this "pharmaceutical
  research plant," the very same facility in reality a nuclear plant,
  becomes involved romatically with the Paul's mother Elizabeth (Jill
  Eikenberry) and friends with Paul. While Dr Mathewson is visiting, Paul
  and Jenny steal the plutonium and construct their own atomic bomb for
  a science fair in New York City.

Although not specifically a Bigtrak car:

 ...another radio-controlled (RC) car was used to help steal a bottle of
 plutonium out of the lab, replacing the existing bottle with one
 containing a shampoo and glitter mix.

Here's the RC car scene:




Thanks. Film looks great and i'm going to watch it. But it's not the one i'm looking for. Think the kids were younger.
